# Gradle error: Could not find method jar() for arguments

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm writing a custom plugin which adds some data to manifest of Java project.

It looks something like this:

```
package com.example.gradle

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

public class ExamplePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    def apply(Project project) {
        project.jar() {
            manifest {
                attributes 'buildServer': checkIfIsBuildServer()
                attributes 'personalBuild': checkIfIsPersonalBuild()
            }
        }
    }

    def checkIfIsBuildServer() {
        return 'some result'
    }

    def checkIfIsPersonalBuild() {
        return 'some result'
    }

}
```

When I'm trying to apply it to some project, I get an error:

```
Could not find method jar() for arguments [com.example.gradle.ExamplePlugin$_apply_closure1@411e4f5e] on project ':SomeProject' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

I am reasonably sure this is some missing import. I don't have any idea how to determine what import it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jar()` isn’t a method on [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html).

If I’m understanding your code correctly, what you are trying to do is configure the `jar` task that is created from the [Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html).

So you need to:

1. Get the task
2. Configure the task

Something like:

```
import org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin
import org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar

public class ExamplePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    def apply(Project project) {
        project.afterEvaluate {
            project.tasks.named(JavaPlugin.JAR_TASK_NAME, Jar) {
                it.manifest {
                    attributes 'buildServer': checkIfIsBuildServer()
                    attributes 'personalBuild': checkIfIsPersonalBuild()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    def checkIfIsBuildServer() {
        'some result'
    }

    def checkIfIsPersonalBuild() {
        'some result'
    }
}
```

I **highly** recommend switch to Kotlin or Java for your plugin. It will make errors like this trivial to resolve and you will fully understand where things are coming from compared to Groovy’s dynamic nature.

Comment: "No such property: JavaPlugin for class: com.example.gradle.ExamplePlugin"

Comment: But I don't know. I apply this plugin to itself through `GroovyClassLoader` and it works so the code itself seems to be correct.

Comment: OK, I've imported `org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin` but now I have error `No such property: Jar for class: com.example.gradle.ExamplePlugin`.

Comment: You have to import `Jar` as well. I left out imports since I assume you’re working with an IDE like Intellij=J which will handle imports for you. https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/jvm/tasks/Jar.html

Comment: hmmm, now I have `Task with name 'jar' not found in project ':SomeProject'.` The same result for `plugins { id 'java-library' }` and `plugins { id 'java' }`.

Comment: Nevermind, I've had to enclose it in block `project.afterEvaluate`.

Comment: Please update your answer to take my comments into account so I can accept it.

Comment: Updated answer with comments. Makes sense. Probably because the plugin is lazily created which is why `afterEvaluate` is needed: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.java#L321

Comment: You shouldn't use afterEvaluate. Instead, the ExamplePlugin should apply the JavaPlugin as the first thing it does

Comment: That is one option. Or use https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/PluginManager.html#withPlugin-java.lang.String-org.gradle.api.Action-